# How can I change a GUILayout.Button in editor script text and color and back?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(GameObjectInfo))]
public class GameObjectInfoButton : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        GameObjectInfo myScript = (GameObjectInfo)target;

        var style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.button);
        style.normal.textColor = Color.red;

        if (myScript.useButton == false)
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        if(myScript.objectsinfo.Length == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Search"))
        {
            myScript.Search();
        }

        GUILayout.Space(70);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Compare"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want that if `myScript.objectsinfo.Length == 0` then disable the button "Search" change the font color to Red change the text to "No Results".

And if myScript.objectsinfo.Length is large then 0 change the button back to black color font and the text "Search".

And keep one button only the `if (GUILayout.Button("Search"))` just switch the colors and text according to the myScript.objectsinfo.Length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Disable the Button
EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(myScript.objectsinfo.Length == 0);
{
    // change fontColor
    var originalFontColor = GUI.contentColor;
    if(myScript.objectsinfo.Length == 0) GUI.contentColor = Color.Red;
    {
        // Change the text
        if (GUILayout.Button(myScript.objectsinfo.Length == 0 ? "No Results" :"Search"))
        {
                myScript.Search();
        }
    }
    // reset back to normal color
    GUI.contentColor = originalFontColor;
}
EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
```

I just add the additional `{` `}` to clean the code a bit since EditorCode usually gets very complex.

References:

- [GUI.contentColor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-contentColor.html)
- [EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup.html) & [EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup.html)
- [? (also ternary) operator](https://learn.microsoft.comdotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)